# Best practice core data same view for creating and editing

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I try to use core data to store persistent data on an iOS device. I've got user flows to create and edit domain objects with a few related and deeply nested objects.

Those user flows are very similar, so I would like to use the same views for those tasks, just deciding on appear if the view got an existing domain object passed or it needs to create a new one.

After testing different approaches, nothing seems to fit this context so I wonder if there are recommended ways for this situation?

The following options got tested:

- initializing the core data object in `init()` results in an `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.` warning
- initializing the core data object in `.onAppear` requires the `@ObservedObject var domainObjectPassed: DomainObject` to be optional, not quite what I'm looking for as well

Any suggestions?

---

Already did that. I extracted the same logic into one view and have two distinct wrapper views that should handle this problem. But I've got the same situation one level higher.

```
struct CreateView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var domainObject: DomainObject

    init(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
      domainObject = DomainObject(context: moc)
      domainObject.id = UUID()

      try? moc.save()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomizeView(domainObject: domainObject)
    }
}
```

-> results in warning from the first option

```
struct CreateView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @ObservedObject private var domainObject: DomainObject? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomizeView(domainObject: domainObject)
         .onAppear {
           ...
         }
    }
}
```

-> requires `domainObject` in `CustomizeView` to be optional, not what I'm looking for

Comment: Handle the problem the next level up, either pass in an existing object, or create a new one and pass that in.

Comment: @jrturton provided a details answer for your suggestion.

Comment: Donny Wals provides a brilliant generic solution on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8rqjs_CNsk) with a child context.

Comment: @andreas.teich: I have the same concept, using only one view for editing or creating. I am defining an optional core data object in the view and it works pretty well: if the object is `nil`, create a new one then edit, otherwise edit the object that was passed. Why are you ruling that out, if I may ask?

Comment: @HunterLion could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same concept (one view for editing and creating), but in my case I find myself comfortable using an optional to get the core data object. If you can live with an optional, this could work.

In this way, you just need to check if the object passed is nil: if it is, create the object, otherwise use the object passed.

In a very schematic way, the view could be:

```
struct EditOrCreate: View {

    var coreDataObject: MyCoreDataEntity

    // Optional object at initializer
    init(objectPassed: MyCoreDataEntity? = nil) {
        if objectPassed == nil {
            coreDataObject = MyCoreDataEntity(context: thePersistentContainerContext)
        } else {
            coreDataObject = objectPassed!
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        // All the text fields and save
    }
}
```

When creating, just call `EditOrCreate()`.

When editing, just pass the object: `EditOrCreate(objectPassed: theObjectBeingShown)`.

You can also make `coreDataObject` an optional variable (which is what I did in my code), depending on how you want to handle your logic - for example, to cancel the creation before saving: in that case, you need to check for `nil` *after* the user has confirmed the creation of the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Some programmers believe that ["Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil"](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/). What I've seen happens when creating generic view code with only a small number of cases that have not yet been thought through is that after creating the generic version, you realise that you need to customise one of them, so end up trying to override the default behaviour in certain cases, which gets real messy and you would have been better off just with separate versions in the first place.

In SwiftUI, the View structs are lightweight and there is no issue with creating lots of them. Try to break your View structs up to be as small as possible then you can compose them together to form your different use cases.

The time you save could be spent on learning more about how SwiftUI works and fixing the issues in the code you posted. E.g. we don't init objects in the View struct init, or in body. Those need to run fast because that code runs quite frequently and creating objects is a comparably heavy task, also those objects that are created are immediately discarded after SwiftUI has finished building the View struct hierarchy, diffed it from last time, and updated the actual UIKit Views on screen. I highly recommend watching every WWDC SwiftUI video, there is a lot to learn and there is a lot of magic going on under the hood.

Another thing you could spend time learning is Swift generics and protocols. These are powerful ways to build reusable code using value types instead of class inheritance that we would typically use as ObjC/UIKit developers which tends to be buggy. You can read more about here: [Choosing Between Structures and Classes (Apple Developer)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes)

Comment: So thanks for your information and time. That's not the intended way to init the domainObject within the view struct is indeed a point I know and not best practice. But that's why I ask for help, because I don't know where to create an empty domainObject in this context.

Comment: I already extracted every bit into a view where it was possible. The `CustomizeView` should get an initialized domainObject passed. But to make it "passable" I have to initialize the object on level above I guess, when incorporating the `CustomizeView`. But at this point, I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?